# Embedding a manifold with connection in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (also need help with diff. eqs.)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, connections

Say a universe we want to study has two finite spatial dimensions, which we will imagine to describe a square of side length two. For the diff. manifold underlying the Newtonian spacetime with which we choose to study this universe, say we equip the set $M:=\mathbb{R}^{+}_0\times[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ with $\mathcal{O}_{\text{St.}}|_M$ and $$\mathcal{A}:=\{(M,\text{id}_M)\}$$

Our universe has, at the points corresponding to $(t,0,0)\in M$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}_0$, a point mass of 1 unit mass. This means that on a point mass at coordinates $p=(t,x,y)$ acts a gravitational force of $$F_p:=\frac{G}{x^2+y^2}$$
Newtons. We set $G$ to $1$. The force vector on the point mass at $p$ may be described with

$$\widehat{\text{F}}_p:=(\widehat{\text{F}}^0_p,\widehat{\text{F}}^1_p,\widehat{\text{F}}^2_p)\equiv\left(0,\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}{x^2+y^2},\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

This determines the connection $\nabla$ *(I define a connection as a map taking a vector field and a $(p,q)$-tensor field to another $(p,q)$-tensor field that satisfies the Leibnitz rule, agrees with partial differentiation for $(0,0)$-tensor fields, is $C^\infty$-linear w.r.t. the vector field input and respects addition of the tensor field input)* on our manifold, as we set all the connection coefficient functions $\Gamma$ to zero except for $$\Gamma^i_{00}(p):=\widehat{\text{F}}^i_p$$

(A result of the autoparallel equation: Objects in the spacetime $M$ on which no force acts besides gravitation move along straight lines of $M$ as defined by the connection $\nabla$ if and only if we define the $\Gamma$s this way.) I want to find an injective embedding $\phi:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ of this spacetime manifold into three-dimensional Euclidean space such that the pullback connection $\nabla^*$, coming from the Euclidean connection $\nabla^E$, is equal to $\nabla$.

The idea behind this is that we would like to see the spacetime $M$ "unstretched" - with the curvature encoded into its embedding and resulting "weird" shape - in $\mathbb{R}^3$. **What is the best way to calculate what such an embedding of a spacetime would look like? And for which kind of connection carrying manifolds do such $\mathbb{R}^3$ visualizations actually exist?**

My approach of finding a differential equation for an embedding $\phi$ went as follows (I would be very glad for pointing out blunders in the calculation, as otherwise solving the diff. eqs. underneath is meaningless): Per definition, we have $$\nabla^*_X\ \phi^*(s)=\phi^*\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(X)}\ s\right)$$

for any covectors $s\in T^1_0\mathbb{R}^3$. We will define $\phi^{-1}$ as a map from $\phi(M)$ to $M$ by $\phi^{-1}(p)=q$ iff $\phi(q)=p$. This leads to: $$\nabla^*_{e_i}\ \phi^*((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))=\nabla^*_{e_i}\ \in^j=\sum_q-\Gamma^{*q}_{ij}\cdot\in^q=\phi^*\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ (\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j)\right)$$

where $e_i$ and $\in^j$ are the natural basis and induced dual basis vector fields of our chart $(M,\text{id}_M)$ respectively. We *want* for $\Gamma^{*q}_{ij}=\Gamma^q_{ij}$ to hold and hence get:

$$\left(\sum_q-\Gamma^q_{ij}\cdot\in^q\right)(e_k)=\left(\phi^*\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ (\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j)\right)\right)(e_k)=\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ (\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j)\right)(\phi_*(e_k))$$

We start to run into a notational issue here: $\left(\sum_q-\Gamma^q_{ij}\cdot\in^q\right)(e_k)$ is an element of $C^\infty(M)$, but $\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ (\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j)\right)(\phi_*(e_k))$ is an element of $C^\infty(\phi(M))$. The above equality is therefore, technically, not correct. As the latter term stems from the definition of the covector-field-pullback $\phi^*$, the problem is that we forgot an input transformation via $(\phi(\cdot))$ at the end of it, i.e., we *should* write

$$\left(\sum_q-\Gamma^q_{ij}\cdot\in^q\right)(e_k)(\cdot)=\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ (\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j)\right)(\phi_*(e_k))(\phi(\cdot))$$

We will keep this in mind and drop $(\phi(\cdot))$ again. We can calculate the left-hand side of the last result and use the Leibnitz rule for connections on the right-hand side:

$$\sum_q\delta^q_k\cdot(-\Gamma^q_{ij})=\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ (\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j)(\phi_*(e_k))-((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ \phi_*(e_k)\right)$$

This leads to:

$$-\Gamma^k_{ij}=\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ \in^j\bigg((\phi^{-1})^*(\phi_*(e_k))\bigg)-((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ \phi_*(e_k)\right)$$

$$=\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ \in^j(e_k)-((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\nabla^E_{\phi^m_{*i}e^E_m}\ \phi^n_{*k}e^E_n\right)$$

where we use the Einstein summation convention at the lower index and input of $\nabla^E$, define $e^E_i$ as the basis vector fields of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\phi^a_{*b}$ as the coefficient functions of the linear maps between the tangent spaces $T_pM$ and $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ provided by $\phi_*(p)$ for each $p\in M$. Further, we get:

$$-\Gamma^k_{ij}=\nabla^E_{\phi_*(e_i)}\ \delta^j_k-((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot\nabla^E_{e^E_m}\ \phi^n_{*k}e^E_n\right)$$

$$\stackrel{Leibnitz}{=}0-((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot\bigg(\phi^n_{*k}\cdot\nabla^E_{e^E_m}\ e^E_n+(\nabla^E_{e^E_m}\ \phi^n_{*k})\cdot e^E_n\bigg)\right)$$

$$=-((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot\bigg(\phi^n_{*k}\cdot\Gamma^{E\ a}_{mn}\cdot e^E_a+e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot e^E_n\bigg)\right)$$

where $\Gamma^{E\ q}_{ij}$ are the connection coefficient functions of three-dimensional Euclidean space. Per definition, these functions equal zero everywhere. Hence:

$$\Gamma^k_{ij}=((\phi^{-1})^*(\in^j))\left(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot e^E_n\right)=\in^j\left((\phi^{-1})_*\bigg(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot e^E_n\bigg)\right)$$

Due to the linearity of $(\phi^{-1})_*$ we have:

$$\Gamma^k_{ij}=\in^j\left(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot (\phi^{-1})_*(e^E_n))\right)$$

By $(\phi^{-1})_{*a}^b$ we will denote the coefficient functions of the linear maps from $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ to $T_pM$ given by $(\phi^{-1})_*$ at every point $p$ of the image $\phi(M)$. As before, instead of viewing $(\phi^{-1})_{*a}^b$ as a $C^\infty(\phi(M))$ function, as the symbol itself suggests, we will treat it as a $C^\infty(M)$ function via the transformation $(\phi(\cdot))$. Going on, we get:

$$\Gamma^k_{ij}=\in^j\left(\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot (\phi^{-1})^a_{*n}\cdot e_a\right)=\delta^j_a\cdot\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot (\phi^{-1})^j_{*n}$$

Which lets us conclude with:

$$\Gamma^k_{ij}=\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot (\phi^{-1})^j_{*n}\ \stackrel{Einstein}{:\iff}\ \Gamma^k_{ij}=\sum_m\sum_n\phi^m_{*i}\cdot e^E_m(\phi^n_{*k})\cdot (\phi^{-1})^j_{*n}$$

The map $\phi$ we search takes values from $\mathbb{R}^3\supset(\mathbb{R}^{+}_0\times[-1,1]\times[-1,1])$ to $\phi(M)\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, which lets us exercise multivariable calculus on it:

$$\phi^a_{*b}(p)=\frac{\partial\phi^a}{\partial e_b}(p)$$
$$(\phi^{-1})^a_{*b}(\phi(p))=\frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^a(\phi(\cdot))}{\partial e_b}(p)$$

where $\phi^a$ and $(\phi^{-1})^a$ are the $a$th component functions of $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ respectively. This leads us to the following differential equations for $\phi$:

$$\left(\sum_m\sum_n\frac{\partial\phi^m}{\partial e_0}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial e_m}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^n}{\partial e_1}\right)\cdot \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^0}{\partial e_n}\right)(t,x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\left(\sum_m\sum_n\frac{\partial\phi^m}{\partial e_0}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial e_m}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^n}{\partial e_2}\right)\cdot \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^0}{\partial e_n}\right)(t,x,y)=\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}$$

and

$$\left(\sum_m\sum_n\frac{\partial\phi^m}{\partial e_i}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial e_m}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^n}{\partial e_k}\right)\cdot \frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^j}{\partial e_n}\right)(t,x,y)=0$$

for any $(i,j,k)\in\{0,1,2\}^3$ where either $i\neq0$ or $j\neq0$.

**Is this set of equations solvable? Can we find the solution? How to approach this? Are there conventions one should respect in their notation?**

To me it seems that one big problem with this is that we *don't know the codomain* of our unknown $\phi$ - which is of course what I actually want to know. I am very unexperienced in diff. eqs. and have no approach to this. Is it acceptable that both $\phi$ and its inverse appear in the formula? I would also be interested to know if we can feed such complex systems of diff. equations into computational systems like Wolfram Alpha!

Edit: I noticed that, for any invertable differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $$f^{-1}(f(x))=x\implies\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f^{-1}\circ f)\right)(x)=1\implies\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial x}(f(x))\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)=1\implies\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial x}(f(\cdot))=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}(\cdot)$$

Hence, we can replace the partial deriviatives of $\phi^{-1}$ above with $$\frac{\partial(\phi^{-1})^0}{\partial e_n}(\phi(\cdot))=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_n}}(\cdot)$$

Edit 2: Unfortunately unsuccessful attempt: Assume we are really lucky and for all $(m,n)\in\{0,1,2\}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ at least one of the two functions $\frac{\partial\phi^m}{\partial e_0}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial e_m}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^n}{\partial e_2}\right)$ vanish. Then we have:

$$\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}=\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_0}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial e_0}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_0}}\right)(t,x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial e_0}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_2}\right)(t,x,y)$$

In more conventional notation:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial y}\right)(t,x,y)=\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\implies\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial y}(t,x,y)=\int\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}\text{d}t=t\cdot\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\implies\phi^0(t,x,y)=\int t\cdot\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{x^2+y^2}\text{d}y$$

Freely available math software (like Wolfram Alpha) can solve this integral, and so we get:

$$\phi^0(t,x,y)=t\cdot\frac{\text{ln}(y)}{x}-t\cdot\frac{\text{ln}(x^2+y^2)}{2x}$$

If this were true, we would have one coordinate component of our embedding function $\phi$ nailed down. But it fails: If the assumption starting our current approach off holds, we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}{x^2+y^2}=\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_0}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial e_0}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_1}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_0}}\right)(t,x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial e_0}\left(\frac{\partial\phi^0}{\partial e_1}\right)(t,x,y)$$

Which puts the following condition on our calculated component of $\phi$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(t\cdot\frac{\text{ln}(y)}{x}-t\cdot\frac{\text{ln}(x^2+y^2)}{2x}\right)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}{x^2+y^2}$$

But, as simple differentiation shows, this equality is not satisfied.